# Cannot create MS sql stored procedure using SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use the current versions of SQL Server Management Studio with Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit) to create a Stored procedure.
I’m following the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx guideline.
When I get to step 3 and right-click on “Stored Procedures” the popup menu I am presented with does not include the “New Stored Procedure” option.  Instead, at the top of the list of options that are presented is the option “Stored procedure…”  When I click on this I get the ASCI text block “Template Generated from Template Explorer” displayed.
What I was expecting was that the “Specify Values for Template Parameters” Query Editor Pane would have been displayed and that the data I entered into it would have been reflected in the “Template generated from Template Explorer” text block which would have been displayed next.
Can anyone tell me why the “Specify Values for Template Parameters” Query Editor Pane isn’t being displayed?

Comment: Just learn to type in the stored procedure definition yourself, starting with `create procedure`.  I think the GUI just interferes with what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.   Nevertheless the product should conform to the behaviour described in the associated documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can call that dialog by using the key combination Ctrl-Shift-M.

Most likely they are not showing this dialog automatically anymore, in order to let the user change the script first and then call the dialog when ready.

Answer (score 0):

New query tab in `CTRL+K,CTRL+X`, you can use the combination.